# Making simple autocomplete using binary search

Tags: python, binary-search

In a list of tuples(where the first one is string and second one is integer) I had to find all tuples which first element starts with input string , using binary search. Before all that , I lexicographic sorted that list of tuples via first element of tuple , and after that, using binary search, adding tuples, which first element is equal to input string, to the new list. Here's my code

```
def binary_search(x,list):  
    l=0
    r=len(list)-1
    while l<=r:
        m=(r-1)/2+l
        m=int(m)
        if list[m][0][0:len(x)]==x:
            return list[m]
        elif list[m][0][0:len(x)]<x:
            l=m+1
        elif list[m][0][0:len(x)]>x:
            r=m-1
    return -1
```

And then I add list of tuples that I want to new list

```
new_list=[]
s=input()
lexicographic_sort(list) #function that sorts using lambda
a=binary_search(s,list)
while a!=-1:
    new_list.append(a)
    list.remove(a)
    a=binary_search(s,list)

print(new_list)
```

The problem is when I input just 1 character, I got results that I want, but inputting more than 1 character, the program just freeze. The more confusing problem in putting more than 1 character is that, when i remove while loop just to call one binary search, it returns me a tuple, so I don't know why my program freezes. 
The list is `[('school', 312), ('bus', 421), ('scheme', 53), ('and', 423), ('maybe', 143), ('schemes', 53), ('ands', 423), ('maybes', 143), ('schemess', 53), ('andsss', 423), ('maybesss', 143)]`

Input 1:sc 
Output:`[('schemess', 53), ('school', 312), ('scheme', 53), ('schemes', 53)]`

Input 2:may 
Output:(freeze)

Comment: can you post a very small input, for reproduction purposes? Also check the variable name for errors in this post.

Comment: Like @KennyOstrom said, I'd like to see an input.  

It works for me. I defined `lexicographic_sort` as:
`def lexicographic_sort(list): 
    list.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])`

Comment: Sory, didn't understand, I'm gonna post it right now.

Comment: It works with that data, and s = 'bu' or s = 'sc', cannot reproduce. It still works if I make a really long list by just doing that sample data * 10. Are you waiting for input? It's good practice to not use "list" as a variable name, because that is also a class name.

Comment: Able to reproduce with `list` = `[('school', 312), ('bus', 421), ('scheme', 53), ('and', 423), ('maybe', 143),('school', 312), ('and', 423)]` stuck in `elif list[m][0][0:len(x)]>x:`

Comment: I get list index out of range when searching for s = 'xxx'

Comment: @KennyOstrom mine is just empty list, anyway the program doesnt do well on different occasions, that's the main problem, I want that to work even the list have more than hundred elements, which is not the case, just on small size list works

Comment: Look at how you calculate the middle from left and right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In binary search, A major step is looking at the middle element, as described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm (among other places)

```
m = (r+l) // 2
```

You have

```
m=(r-1)/2+l
```

For example, the middle of 9 and 11 would be 10/2+9 = 14. That is not right. This can lead you to look at indexes that are too big for the array, and thus exit the program with IndexError.

You'll want to use // to guarantee an integer result. In this case, rounding down is desired.

It really should have been clear that you are getting an IndexError exception, though. No idea what's up with it supposedly freezing. That part makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

The "moving middle" element should be calculated `m=(r-l)/2+l` but you have `m=(r-1)/2+l`.

It should be:

```
def binary_search(x,list):  
    l=0
    r=len(list)-1
    while l<=r:
        m=(r-l)/2+l
        m=int(m)
        if list[m][0][0:len(x)]==x:
            return list[m]
        elif list[m][0][0:len(x)]<x:
            l=m+1
        elif list[m][0][0:len(x)]>x:
            r=m-1
    return -1
```

Reference: [python binary search](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-binary-search/)

Answer (score 0):

the builtin sort will sort this correctly ... no need for lamda

```
terms = sorted(terms)
```

there is a builtin binary search for sorted lists...

```
import bisect
idx = bisect.bisect(ordered_list_to_search,term)
print("Found: ",idx)
```

so you could say (since it looks like all the numeric values are greater than or equal to 1)

```
idx = bisect.bisect_right(terms,(search_term,0))
if idx < len(terms):
    print(terms[idx])
print("Nothing found...")
```